# Mongoose: Update one value in array objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Good Evening,
I am using the MERN Stack and the Stripe API.
I have a function that loops through the invoices gathered from stripe and returns only the ones that are true.

I want to update the ones that have a changed paid status from false to true.
Right now when I run the loop it overwrites all of the paid statuses to true. I just need it to match the check that the paid status of an id in the Stripe Array doesn't match the one in the dbInvoices array and update just that field.

```js
  async function deletePaidInvoicesFromDB(dbInvoices, stripeInvoices) {

stripeInvoices.forEach((StripeElement) => {
    
  dbInvoices.forEach(async (DBElement) => {
    
    
      if(StripeElement.paid !== DBElement.paid) {
        
        const update = await InvoiceModel.updateMany({id: StripeElement.id }, {
          id: StripeElement.id,
          amount_due: StripeElement.amount_due,
          created: StripeElement.created,
          customer_email: StripeElement.customer_email,
          customer_name: StripeElement.customer_name,
          due_date: StripeElement.due_date,
          hosted_invoice_url: StripeElement.hosted_invoice_url,
          paid: StripeElement.paid,
        }, {upsert: false}).catch((e) => {console.log(e)}) 

    if(update.nModified > 0 ) {
   console.log('Number of Invoices added or updated to DB:', update.nModified)
    }
        
      } 
  })
});
  }

const InvoiceSchema = new Schema ({
id: String,
status: String,
amount_due: Number,
created: Number,
customer_email: String,
customer_name: String,
due_date: Number,
hosted_invoice_url: String,
paid: Boolean
});
```

Comment: Please include the function loop code in your question.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that, but its added.

Comment: I am adding the working code I have figured out, I feel there is an easier way or prettier way of doing things. If you have any suggestions do let me know.

Comment: Could you explain more about your model?. A sample document may be help

Comment: I added the schema to the bottom of the file. Do I need to add something to make them optional?

Comment: So may i confirm that, you just want to update one property `paid` of document instead of write all property, or your want to update `one document` match in dbInvoices and break?

Comment: I just want to update one property `paid` of a many documents (if any)

Comment: May be you miss this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Comment: I am using mongoose it adds the operator for you automatically.